# Does anyone know UIBezierPath IOS similar code in android

Tags: android, ios

I want to use the same/equivalent methods in android to complete the requirement, so does anyone help me with that?
like I want the same code in android.

```
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    // draw x-axis
    x.axis.color.setStroke()
    let y0 = height - self.y.scale(0) - y.axis.inset
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: x.axis.inset, y: y0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width - x.axis.inset, y: y0))
    path.stroke()
    // draw y-axis
    y.axis.color.setStroke()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: x.axis.inset, y: height - y.axis.inset))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x.axis.inset, y: y.axis.inset))
    path.stroke()
```

Comment: I as Android developer have no idea what `UIBezierPath` is. WHat exactly it does, how it works?

Comment: It is similar like "canvas" and "draw" methods in android, I asked because I think someone might give me a trick or tip of code so that will be good.